# Scraping price information from a website with 'show more' button.(cannot get html with all the products)

Tags: python, web-scraping

guys. I am trying to scrape price information from url:"https://www.ocado.com/browse/christmas-317740?display=4879",but the html file I got only contains information about 30 products.I want to know how can I get html file with all the 4879 products in this category "christmas".

`url = "https://www.ocado.com/browse/christmas-317740?display=4879"

response = requests.get(url, headers={'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8'},timeout=15)
response.raise_for_status()
response.encoding = response.apparent_encoding
concent = response.text`

Any suggestions are welcomed.

Comment: have you tried with selenium?

Comment: I am new here, sorry for my formats

Comment: Selenium also get information about 30 products